# How to put content in OpenEdge progress audit tables?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl, progress-db, auditing

I have enabled the default policies, and I see that the table _aud-audit-data is saving system events: Login, logout, add or modify users, changes in policies, things like that.

But I need my ERP events to be saved. For example, deleting a client.

I'm new to auditing and I think I understand that this should be recorded in _aud-audit-data-value.
But it doesn't.

What should I do?

Just seen an specific chapter in the doc: "Developing an Audit-enabled OpenEdge Application"
Reading now...

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the AUDIT-CONTROL system handle.

```
AUDIT-CONTROL:LOG-AUDIT-EVENT( 32000,
                               "This is the event context",
                               "This is the event detail",
                               "This is the user detail"
                             ).
```

This knowledge base article describes this in detail

https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Knowledge/P127541